# Wired network disconnects when using Transmition bitTorrent

Tags: 11.10

Every time I use Transmition BitTorrent my adsl disconnects, and when I try to connect it again it says that there is no network hardware (something like that). so I have to reboot to connect again. It's ok if I surf the net, play online games, download from chrome etc.

Comment: Could it be that your network/ISP is scanning for torrent traffic and killing connections when it detects them?

Comment: Does it happen while downloading or idle?

Comment: What happens to all the lights on the ADSL modem when this happens?

Comment: it happends only when I'm downloading torrent. Light are normal, only light number 1 stops blinking

Comment: I don't think it's ISP fault because after it disconnects I can't see my network card, I have to reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reduced number of connections per torrent, and my problem is gone.